# How to workaround "SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. " error

Tags: sql-server

I'm experiencing an error in sql server 2014 (SP2), when I try to run a 'create table' sql statement after SET ANSI_PADDING OFF. The statement fails with error message

> "Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure log, Line 7
>   SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'."

This used to work fine (although I haven't explicitly tried it in a while on my sql server instance).

-- code that generates error:
use test
set ansi_padding off
create table test_ap3 (i int)

-- code that runs fine:
use test
set ansi_padding on
create table test_ap3 (i int)

Note: The create table with 'set ansi_padding off' works fine on other sql servers (i've tried it very recently on sql server 2014 SP3 standard edition, and sql server 2016 too).
I tried creating a new database on my local server, and the issue does not occur on the new database. The options settings for both dbs are the same. Old db had compatibility level set to 2012, but even after I changed it to 2014 the issue still occurrs.

Comment: Why do you need to `set ansi_padding off` on the table? This may also help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3cd22f1b-cefd-47fb-85dc-4c12deddac30/select-failed-because-the-following-set-options-have-incorrect-settings-ansinulls?forum=databasedesign

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it does not help explain or resolve the issue. I do understand ANSI_PADDING is deprecated, but it has not been removed, so it should still work.

Comment: You checked that you have no DDL triggers on the database, as per the link? What specifically do you need `ansi_padding off` for?

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be caused by code in a database level trigger "for create table". The trigger has code with xml operations, and xml operations will fail if ANSI_PADDING is off!